# Count by Title on specific columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, join, func

```
Date       ID       intent 
9/1/2018    1   fetch it 
9/1/2018    1   Ask it
9/1/2018    1   default
9/1/2018    2   remand
9/1/2018    2   choose it
9/2/2018    1   fetch it 
9/2/2018    1   choose 
9/2/2018    1   default
9/3/2018    4   Ask it
9/3/2018    4   fetch it 
9/4/2018    5   hello
9/4/2018    1   call
9/4/2018    1   default
9/5/2018    1   remand
9/5/2018    1   default
9/5/2018    2   fetch it 
9/5/2018    2   default
```

For the above table : I am trying to get the following output...Can you please help here...

count of intents that have intent followed by default on a day to day basis

```
9/1/2018    1
9/2/2018    1
9/3/2018    0
9/4/2018    1
9/5/2018    2
```

Name of intents that have intent followed by default  on a daily basis

```
9/1/2018    ask it
9/2/2018    choose
9/3/2018    
9/4/2018    call
9/5/2018    remand 
9/5/2018    fetch it
```

Count of ID's that have intent followed by  default on a day to day basis

```
9/1/2018    1
9/2/2018    1
9/3/2018    0
9/4/2018    1
9/5/2018    2
```

Thanks...

Comment: what have you tried so far?  and when you say "followed by" how are the records sorted?

Comment: To answer your question, we need to know the sort order and the version of SQL Server you are using. Also: What is the difference between "count of intents" and "count of ID's"? What does "have intent" mean?

Comment: Duplicate of [msdn post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9f034d72-99b2-4a10-ae05-af5d1ef47837/count-by-title-on-specific-columns?forum=transactsql)

Comment: The version I am using is SQL server 17...sorted by date , ID ,intent asc

Comment: What does "followed by" mean?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your data does not appear to have an explicit ordering.

Comment: The top 3 according to your ordering of date,id,intent are not in the correct order.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Clarify via post edit, not comment. And what is your question? Please do not dump homework/specifications. Show your work & what parts you can do & say how you are stuck. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: @ Tom, Gordon ,Wolfgang ..I will going forward make sure that I write the questions with utmost clarity....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    DECLARE @Sample TABLE
    (
        theDate DATE NOT NULL,
        ID INT NOT NULL,
        Intent VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    );

INSERT  @Sample
VALUES  ('20180901', 1, 'fetch it'),
    ('20180901', 1, 'Ask it'),
    ('20180901', 1, 'default'),
    ('20180901', 2, 'remand'),
    ('20180901', 2, 'choose it'),
    ('20180902', 1, 'fetch it'),
    ('20180902', 1, 'choose'),
    ('20180902', 1, 'default'),
    ('20180903', 4, 'Ask it'),
    ('20180903', 4, 'fetch it'),
    ('20180904', 5, 'hello'),
    ('20180904', 1, 'call'),
    ('20180904', 1, 'default'),
    ('20180905', 1, 'remand'),
    ('20180905', 1, 'default'),
    ('20180905', 2, 'fetch it'),
    ('20180905', 2, 'default');

-- swePeso
WITH cteData(theDate, Task1, Task2, Task3)
AS (
    SELECT      theDate,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Intent = 'default' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Task1,
            MIN(CASE WHEN Intent = 'default' THEN NULL ELSE Intent END) AS Task2,
            MAX(CASE WHEN Intent = 'default' THEN ID ELSE NULL END) AS Task3
    FROM        @Sample
    GROUP BY    theDate,
            ID
)
SELECT      theDate,
        SUM(Task1) AS Task1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Task1 = 1 THEN Task2 ELSE '' END) AS Task2,
        COUNT(DISTINCT Task3) AS Task3
FROM        cteData
GROUP BY    theDate
ORDER BY    theDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with first sample output :

```
select Date, sum(case when intent = 'default' then 1 else 0 end) 
from table t
group by Date;
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh!..Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

is this helpful.?

```
    Create Table #tmp([Date] Date,ID int, intent Varchar(10))

    Insert into #tmp
    SELECT '9/1/2018',1,'fetch it' Union All
    SELECT '9/1/2018',1,'Ask it' Union All
    SELECT '9/1/2018',1,'default' Union All
    SELECT '9/1/2018',2,'remand' Union All
    SELECT '9/1/2018',2,'choose it' Union All
    SELECT '9/2/2018',1,'fetch it' Union All
    SELECT '9/2/2018',1,'choose' Union All
    SELECT '9/2/2018',1,'default' Union All
    SELECT '9/3/2018',4,'Ask it' Union All
    SELECT '9/3/2018',4,'fetch it' Union All
    SELECT '9/4/2018',5,'hello' Union All
    SELECT '9/4/2018',1,'call' Union All
    SELECT '9/4/2018',1,'default' Union All
    SELECT '9/5/2018',1,'remand'Union All
    SELECT '9/5/2018',1,'default' Union All
    SELECT '9/5/2018',2,'fetch it' Union All
    SELECT '9/5/2018',2,'default' 


    ;with cte
    As
    (
        Select *,LEAD(intent) over(partition by [Date] order by (Select null)) as FollowingIntent
        from #tmp   
    )

    Select Date, SUM(CASE WHEN FollowingIntent='default' then 1 else 0 end)
    from cte
    Group by [Date]

    Drop Table #tmp
```